# Ksqldb - unable to update a table using 'create or replace' because of mismatch of key format, but both table versions have the same key format

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a ksqldb table defined like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer_total_orders WITH (
  kafka_topic = 'warehouse.customer_total_orders',
  value_format = 'JSON_SR',
  key_format = 'JSON_SR'
) AS
    SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) as orders_count, SUM(price) as total_spending
    FROM enriched_orders 
    GROUP BY customer_id
    EMIT CHANGES;
```

Now i try to update the table query using `create or replace` syntax like so (added customer_name as well):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE customer_total_orders WITH (
  kafka_topic = 'warehouse.customer_total_orders',
  value_format = 'JSON_SR',
  key_format = 'JSON_SR'
) AS
    SELECT customer_id, customer_name, COUNT(*) as orders_count, SUM(price) as total_spending
    FROM enriched_orders 
    GROUP BY customer_id, customer_name
    EMIT CHANGES;
```

But I get this error:

`Cannot upgrade data source: DataSource 'CUSTOMER_TOTAL_ORDERS' has topic = KsqlTopic{kafkaTopicName='warehouse.customer_total_orders', keyFormat=KeyFormat{format=FormatInfo{format=JSON_SR, properties={}}, features=[UNWRAP_SINGLES], window=Optional.empty}, valueFormat=ValueFormat{format=FormatInfo{format=JSON_SR, properties={}}, features=[]}} which is not upgradeable to KsqlTopic{kafkaTopicName='warehouse.customer_total_orders', keyFormat=KeyFormat{format=FormatInfo{format=JSON_SR, properties={}}, features=[], window=Optional.empty}, valueFormat=ValueFormat{format=FormatInfo{format=JSON_SR, properties={}}, features=[]}}`

the only difference here is that in the original table the KeyFormat `features=[UNWRAP_SINGLES]` but in the new table the KeyFormat `features=[]`

I don't understand how this is possible considering both have the same configuration.
I would love some help solving the issue.
Thank you.